# MySQL database keep historic changes (like a wiki)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've got a site where I let the users change a couple of pages but now I'd like to somehow keep a track of those changes and show them to the rest of the users. (something like a wiki I guess)

Here is what I've currently got:

```
id, title, description, country, language, last_update (and ~20+ more fields)
```

I was thinking of making a main table with the ID and the last history_ID and then the history table get all the above so each new entry will get a new history_ID and all the new entries.

I feel though that I could do it better. Because with the method above I will end up with a ton of similar rows (just altering a single field or a letter or something).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You can't do better, that's the way to go. So what if you end up with similar rows? The point is that you can get exactly the data you need at exact point in history, and that's excellent. Database's job is to deal with data, not to scratch itches when we get the tingling spiderman sense that we could do better by implementing some hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right idea. You need two tables and they should look similar to:

```
create table page (
  id bigint primary key not null,
  title varchar(100) not null,
  -- More columns here.
  -- The last version of the content column can added here as redundancy,
  --   for performance reasons.
  last_version_id bigint, -- allows null
);

create table page_version (
  id bigint primary key not null,
  content mediumtext not null,
  page_id bigint not null,
  constraint fk_pv_page foreign key (page_id)
    references page (id)
);

alter table page add 
  constraint fk_page_version foreign key (last_version_id)
    references page_version (id);
```

The last version of the content column can added in the `page` table (would be redundant) to improve performance when reading/displaying the pages.

Reading pages is usually far more common than updating them so the redundancy can make your site faster.

Please note the column `last_version_id` allows null values, so you can actually insert/update a row in MySQL (that doesn't implement constraint check deferrability).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'd like to make a few Qs though if you don't mind. I was thinking of showing the last version from the page table directly anyway, was there a different way? Also the content column on the page_version table what is it for? Thanks!

Comment: The `page` table can only store a single version of `content` for every page, presumably the last/current one. The `content` column in the `page_version` table stores all versions of the content from the beginning of time. The `content` column in the `page` table is optional: if not present you can retrieve the last version using a simple `join` between both tables.

Comment: If you consider this answer is goog, please upvote it and/or accept it!

Comment: Can you please give me an example of the above scenario? Since I want to track the users and their changes (so user/date) and the 25ish columns that are editable (from title/description/etc) which are not placed in a single big text. Thank you!

Comment: The first time the page is created you insert 1 row in `page` and 1 row the first version of the content in `page_version` -- easy. The second time (the page is updated) you **update** the `page` row and **insert** a second row in `page_version`. This way `page` has alwasy the last version of the page, while `page_version` keeps all versions of the page (forever).